# Node Js saving to a txt file not working

Tags: node.js

I have a server running on Node Js. What I'm doing is whenever the users submit something to save their input to a text file. When I run my server as a localhost it works and saves the input to the file. Whenever I run it on the real published server it doesn't. Is there a way to accomplish it on the real server without a database?

My code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
const log=require('simple-node-logger').createSimpleLogger();
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
var port = process.env.PORT || 8081;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/server'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname +'/images'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile('main.html');
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Server is running on port:' + port);
});

app.post('/submit', function(req, res){
  var data = fs.writeFileSync('fileSync', req.body.rank, 'utf8');
  return res.sendFile('success.html');
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So what happens?

Comment: When it's not on the localhost, nothing. No file is created and nothing is saved. @ralphtheninja

Comment: `fs.writeFileSync()` returns `undefined` i guess no point in saving it into `var data`. The file should be saved, but on the server app is running, which in this case is not localhost

Comment: some details about how you have hosted the node app ,etc will help

Comment: @GabrielaBoyadjiyska Not even an exception thrown? Make sure you know exactly what current working directory is. You could also specify an absolute path. Might have to do with permissions.

Comment: @damitj07  have my project hosted by the university server (http://gazeexperiment.inf.unibz.it:8081). I specify it like this:

app.post('/submit', function(req, res){
fs.writeFileSync('fileSync', req.body.rank, 'utf8');
 return res.sendFile('/var/www/html/gazeexperiment.inf.unibz.it/success.html');
});

Comment: @ralphtheninja no exceptions thrown

Comment: @GabrielaBoyadjiyska which version of express are you using?